# How can I add space in price

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, product-attribute, tierprice

I have this on my site

[image]

how when i select optione

[image]

how do i get the space back in between

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also faced this issue and got fixed from admin section.
Go to Admin: System > Manage Currency > Symbol > You will see as:
[image: Manage Currency Symbols]

Just uncheck the currency which you want to edit. And put space after the currency symbol.